# How do I index regular expressions in Elastic Stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Using ELK/Elastic Stack for log management, I want to build reports based on log lines like this:

```
2018-01-31 11:50:00.212 Loading the user images took 234 ms 
2018-01-31 10:23:01.984 Loading the user images took 331 ms 
2018-01-31 10:12:41.323 Loading the user images took 512 ms
```

So, the report would take lines with the string `Loading the user images took`

Then the regex would extract the number as in `/took (\d+) ms/` and build a chart or notification.

How do I do this? Perhaps this involves defining an index somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use logstash grok filters.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Use this site to test your grok patterns user-friendly way:

> http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

I made a pattern that extracts the ms to a timeTaken field:

```
%{GREEDYDATA}took %{NUMBER:timeTaken}
```

If you need more data, use the online page for testing and search for grok patterns. Visualization is done in Kibana.